TS infer wrong type for function
Hello everyone i have a code like this:
import { z } from "zod"

export const { object, string, array, union, literal } = z

type AddressKind = "residence" | "legal"

export function address<TKind extends AddressKind>(kind: TKind) {
    const base = object({
        street: z.string().max(50),
    })

    switch (kind) {
        case "residence": {
            return base.merge(
                object({
                    flat: z.optional(z.string().max(10)),
                }),
            )
        }

        case "legal": {
            return base.merge(
                object({
                    office: z.optional(z.string().max(10)),
                }),
            )
        }

        default: {
            throw new Error("Unexpected kind")
        }
    }
}

export type Address<Kind extends AddressKind> = z.infer<ReturnType<typeof address<Kind>>>

export type LegalAdress = Address<"legal">
// type LegalAdress = {
//     street: string;
//     flat?: string | undefined;
// } | {
//     street: string;
//     office?: string | undefined;
// }

I expect that LegalAdress type is
{
    street: string;
    office?: string | undefined;
}

but right now it is a union:
type LegalAdress = {
 street: string;
 flat?: string | undefined;
} | {
 street: string;
 office?: string | undefined;
}

why does this happen and how to fix it?
Playground

Do you want to tag this with zod if the question depends on it, or could you [edit] to remove that from your code example if it doesn't?

Added a tag. If this can be done using zod then I would like such a solution

Sure, but I'm no expert in zod so I'll disengage. Good luck.

I dont thing so. Maybe u try to write answer and maybe this help me

What? I don't understand what you mean, sorry. I can't try to write an answer if it depends on a whole library I don't use and don't feel like digging through.

I don’t think that the solution to my problem depends on the zod library and it will be the same whether I use it or not. After all, it makes no difference what is returned from the switch

But your example depends on zod. If your question doesn't depend on it, then you should [edit] the example to remove that dependency so it's a [mre]. If you can't figure out how to do that because you don't know zod or TS well enough, that's unfortunate, but I'm not in a position to help because I don't know zod enough either. If someone can come along who can answer with the question as-is, great.  In any case, I'm going to disengage now unless I see an edit that has purely TypeScript code without third-party library imports. Good luck!

Pavel, I added a response below.

You can streamline the code by creating a mapping type that links each AddressKind to its respective schema. This mapping object can also serve as the source for deriving the possible values of the AddressKind type.
This should work:

Note: The throw new Error line does not even need to be in address, because you will get the type at compile time. You can simply return schemas[kind].

import { z } from "zod";

const baseSchema = z.object({
    street: z.string().max(50),
});

const schemas = {
    residence: baseSchema.merge(
        z.object({
            flat: z.optional(z.string().max(10)),
        })
    ),
    legal: baseSchema.merge(
        z.object({
            office: z.optional(z.string().max(10)),
        })
    ),
} as const;

export type AddressKind = keyof typeof schemas; // "residence" | "legal"

export function address(kind: AddressKind) {
    const schema = schemas[kind];
    if (!schema) {
        throw new Error("Unexpected kind"); // This is not really needed
    }
    return schema;
}

export type Address<Kind extends AddressKind> = z.infer<typeof schemas[Kind]>;

export type LegalAddress = Address<"legal">;
export type ResidenceAddress = Address<"residence">;

Inferred types:
type AddressKind = "residence" | "legal"

type LegalAddress = {
    street: string;
    office?: string | undefined;
}

type ResidenceAddress = {
    street: string;
    flat?: string | undefined;
}

Usage:
const legalAddressData: LegalAddress = {
    street: "123 Legal St",
    office: "Suite 100",
};

const residenceAddressData: ResidenceAddress = {
    street: "456 Residence Ave",
    flat: "Apt 2B",
};

// Validate the data using the Zod schemas
const legalAddress = address('legal').parse(legalAddressData);
const residenceAddress = address('residence').parse(residenceAddressData);

